# Need a hint where to start with combining

Tags: c#, c

I,m new to this forum and hope to find a hint or answer to the next hypothetical problem:
There are 9 boxes. Three rows of three. I pick one as a start. From that start i have to combine it with three more boxes. The start box included so a total of 4. The combination has to be that the boxes are all connect to each other with at least one side. So a max combination/permutation search won't work i'll guess? Then i get combinations that are not allowed.
Just need a hint where/how to start.

Comment: Are you trying find the number of all valid combinations? Or just a single valid combination, starting from the box you picked randomly?

Comment: I'm trying to find a number of all valid combinations from the box i pickes.

Comment: You could consider all the different Tetris pieces including mirror images and rotations, and use their widths and heights to determine how many ways there are to fit each one into a 3x3 box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the boxes and their spatial relationshiop as

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

With only 9 boxes, you'll have `9! / (5! * 4!) == 126` possible combinations.

You could enumerate them all and filter out the invalid ones.

- given a combination (4 integers, each a box number)
- it's invalid if it doesn't contain the box you picked randomly
- it's invalid if any member isn't +/- 1 or +/3 of any other member

Comment: I'm trying to understand your equation. So, you use the factorial of 9 (al possible combinations) and then divide by 5! * 4!. I'm ashamed to say I'm lost here.....

Comment: @Techie That's just the formula for nCr (choose r items out of n): n! / (r! * (n-r)!)

Comment: @mr. Fixit Do you have an example in C how to create a list of all these combinations?

Comment: yes! but a) can you pose that as a separate question (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). b) if you agree i've answered your request for 'a hint', please 'accept' this answer.

Comment: 2nd hint: search SO for '[c] generate permutation'

Comment: @mr.Fixit I tried to ask it as a sperate question but the first question was negative voted by this community so i can't ask more questions for now.....thanks anyway. I apriciate your answers and help!

Comment: Did you try searching StackOverflow ("SO") for '[c] generate permutation'?